# Update files in vendored library

Tags: go

I need to make some changes to a file in one of the vendored libraries.

What is the best way to go about it?

Maybe:

```sh
 1. fork repo
 2. make changes
 3. update dependencies to use fork
 (4.) make pr to original repo
```

Comment: read the license first.

Comment: You can fork and modify all repos with open sources licenses. Or what do you mean?

Comment: A license may prohibit distributing modified versions of the library. If the license permits, your approach sounds fine. You could consider replacing step 3 with getting the change merged in the upstream repo if it may benefit others, too.

Comment: It also hugely depends on whether your own project is a F/OSS or it's some code base developed and used "in house" by your $dayjob_enterprise. In the latter case you can do whatever you want. In the former case it's probably best to discuss the changes with the developer(s) of the package and may be work on pull request (and in the interim use a fork; `go mod` supports the `replace` directive in the `go.mod` files specifically for this case).

Comment: agreed. When its beneficial to others always try to make a PR to the original repo and see if the author of the repo is interested in merging the changes. 
Thanks for the tip with the replace.

Comment: It would be great to just merge to the original repo, but most likely that will take a while in most cases

Answer (score 7):

I would advise not modifying the `vendor` directory yourself except for temporary debugging. Instead, in general the process today would be something like the following.

---

1. For the sake of simplicity, remove the existing `vendor` directory while you work. (You'll rebuild it later with your changes.)

```
$ rm -r ./vendor
```

---

2. Clone the upstream repo (or your own fork of the upstream repo) to a local directory. (Be sure to read the upstream maintainer's license, `README`, and/or contributing guide so that you understand their process for testing, code review, etc.!)

```
$ git clone https://github.com/julian59189/somerepo
```

As part of this step, you may need to add a `go.mod` file if the upstream repo doesn't already have one.

```
$ pushd ./somerepo
$ go mod init example.com/somerepo
$ popd
```

---

3. Add a [`replace` directive](https://golang.org/ref/mod#go-mod-file-replace) to your `go.mod` file to point the dependency to the fork. (For more detail, see [Developing and testing against unpublished module code](https://golang.org/doc/modules/managing-dependencies#unpublished).)

```
$ go mod edit -replace example.com/somerepo@someversion=./somerepo
```

---

4. Make and test the change in your local clone, and push it to your fork. Record the commit hash for later use.

```
…
$ go test ./... example.com/somerepo/...
$ pushd ./somerepo
$ git commit -a
$ COMMIT=$(git rev-parse HEAD)
$ git push
$ popd
```

---

5. Send an upstream PR for the change, following the upstream author's instructions.

---

6. (optional) If you expect the PR to take a while to be merged, at this point you may want to update the `replace` directive to point to the published fork instead of the local clone.

```
$ go mod edit -replace example.com/somerepo@someversion=github.com/julian59189/somerepo@$COMMIT
$ go mod tidy
```

Now anyone who checks out your repo and works *within your module* will use the fixed version, even if they re-run `go mod vendor` (for example, to pick up an unrelated fix in a different module).

---

7. (optional) Rebuild your local `vendor` directory, if you use one, with the replacement in effect, and commit the changes. At this point, your own module itself is fixed, but nobody who uses your module will see the fix (because you are not the authoritative owner of the upstream module).

```
$ go mod vendor
$ git add go.mod go.sum vendor
$ git commit
```

---

8. Once the upstream PR is merged, drop your `replace` directive and update to the latest upstream. (If the upstream author hasn't tagged a release yet, you can use a [pseudo-version](https://golang.org/ref/mod#pseudo-versions) by passing a specific commit hash to `go get` instead of `latest`; see [Getting a specific commit using a repository identifier](https://golang.org/doc/modules/managing-dependencies#repo_identifier).)

```
$ go mod edit -dropreplace=example.com/somerepo@someversion
$ go get -d example.com/somerepo@latest
$ go mod tidy
$ go mod vendor  # If you want to keep a vendor directory going forward.
$ git add go.mod go.sum vendor
$ git commit
```

Answer (score 2):

Regardless of the license, from a pragmatic point of view it depends a lot on the circumstances.

- If it is a critical bug affecting your production -> modifying vendor is probably the fastest way but the main drawback is that the fix should be cherry-picked each time the library is updated.
- If is a *nice to have thing* or is not compromised in your backlog -> PR will benefit your project and also the community. Moreover, updating a version would be as easy as change it on the `go.mod` file.
- Forking is the long path of modifying vendor, it has all drawbacks and one more: maintain an extra repository.

In any case, avoid license restrictions with FREE software LIBRE is quite important.